# Understanding query method where in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I want to return the count of users that that have a boolean value, `show`, not set to true. `show` is a boolean but is initialized to `nil`.

Because of this I'm getting some results that I did not expected. For example,

```rb
[{show: nil}].where.not(show: true).count -> 0
```

```rb
[{show: nil}].where(show: [nil, false]).count -> 1
```

Shouldn't this query's return the same thing?

Comment: Can you fix the database schema? Allowing `null` in a boolean column rarely makes sense, would probably be better making the column `not null default false` so that you don't have to worry about the nulls at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a general misunderstanding of `NULL` (which is not uncommon by the way).

`NULL` is not comparable, it is neither true or false, nor equal or not equal, nor less than or greater than, etc., `NULL` cannot even be compared to `NULL`. e.g. `NULL = NULL` is false but `NULL != NULL` is also false.

Your First case (`.where.not(show: true)`) is `show != true` (or `NOT(show =true)`) which is the equivalent of `show = false`.

Your second example (`.where(show: [nil, false])`) is `show IS NULL OR show = false`. While this syntax `show: [x,y]` usually results in an `IN()` clause `Arel` is smart enough to realize that one of these values is `nil` and converts the SQL generation accordingly because `show IN (NULL,false)` would be equivalent to `show = NULL OR show = false` (this is how `IN()` works) but as mentioned `NULL = NULL` is false thus why `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` exist.

The result of your query is because there are no rows where show = false but there is one row where show IS NULL.